# ImportError running source code in virtualenv interpreter, but not when trying to do import direct in console

Tags: python, bash, virtualenv, gdata, importerror

I'm using virtualenv to set up my python environment to run some scripts. When I run the scripts I am getting import errors for only one of my packages - gdata.

I can manually activate my virtualenv in the console, enter the interpreters interactive mode, and successfully import the gdata modules in there without error. But when I run a script from inside my virtual env, which imports the exact same modules, I get `ImportError`

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File ".../src/writer/gdata.py", line 4, in <module>
    from gdata.docs.client import DocsClient
ImportError: No module named docs.client
```

Here is what my virtualenv setup script looks like (although I'm not sure that it's relevant or really helps)

```
import textwrap, virtualenv

output = virtualenv.create_bootstrap_script(textwrap.dedent("""
import os, subprocess
def after_install(options, home_dir):
    etc = join(home_dir, 'etc')
    if not os.path.exists(etc):
        os.makedirs(etc)
    subprocess.call([join(home_dir, 'bin', 'easy_install'),
                     'gdata==2.0.18'])
    subprocess.call([join(home_dir, 'bin', 'easy_install'), 
                     'numpy']), '--upgrade'
    subprocess.call([join(home_dir, 'bin', 'easy_install'),
                     'pandas==0.13.0'])
    subprocess.call([join(home_dir, 'bin', 'pip'), 'install',
                     'python-dateutil==2.2'])
"""))
f = open('env-bootstrap.py', 'w').write(output)
```

And here is the main bash script I am running to activate the virtualenv and run the script which is throwing the error:

```
#!/bin/bash
set -e 
python env-setup.py
echo "Setup has run"
python env-bootstrap.py $HOME/virtualenv/my-virtualenv/ --verbose
echo "Bootstrap has run"
echo `which python`
source $HOME/virtualenv/my-virtualenv/bin/activate

echo "Virtualenv activated"
echo `which python`
python src/main.py

deactivate
```

I am using which python to make sure when after activating the virtualenv the right version of the interpreter is definitely being used - which can also be confirmed by the fact I'm not getting import errors for pandas or numpy..

Any ideas on how to resolve?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently you have a `gdata` module of your own in `src/writer/gdata.py`, and Python thinks *that* is the `gdata` you are looking for, not the package you have installed into your virtualenv. Try renaming your `gdata.py` to something else.

Comment: Oooooooooh!!!! I can't believe I didn't even think of that. Seems so obvious now. Thank you!